# When fitting Tweedie GLM in SAS, should I use the scale option?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sas, tweedie-distribution

In SAS `proc genmod` with `dist=tweedie`, when would you use `scale=pearson` or `scale=deviance`?

In either case we get a message

```
The Tweedie dispersion parameter was held fixed.
```

but without scale option it says

```
The Tweedie dispersion parameter was estimated by maximum likelihood.
```

Wouldn't it be better to estimate the dispersion parameter, i.e. not use the `scale` option? And why are standard errors smaller in that case?

Answer (score 1):

The SCALE= option is designed for distributions that do not contain a parameter that scales the variance (for example, Poisson).  For those distributions, you can use the SCALE= option to account for overdispersion.

In contrast, [the Tweedie distribution contains a scaling/dispersion parameter](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_details28.htm) as part of the three-parameter distribution. So, yes, it would be better to estimate this parameter by MLE.  There is no need to use the SCALE= option for Tweedie.